# Growth rates, using the last non-NA value by groups

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   value id
1      2  A
2      5  A
3     NA  A
4      7  A
5      9  A
6      1  B
7     NA  B
8     NA  B
9      5  B
10     6  B
```

And I would like to calculate growth rates of the value using the id variable to group. Usually, I would do something like this:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(growth = log(value) - as.numeric(lag(value)))
```

To get this dataframe:

```
   value    id     growth
   (dbl) (chr)      (dbl)
1      2     A         NA
2      5     A -0.3905621
3     NA     A         NA
4      7     A         NA
5      9     A -4.8027754
6      1     B         NA
7     NA     B         NA
8     NA     B         NA
9      5     B         NA
10     6     B -3.2082405
```

Now what I want to do is to use the last non NA value as well for the growth rates. Kind of like calculating the growth rates over the "NA-gaps" as well. For example: In row 4 should be the growth rate from 5 to 7 and in row 9 should be the growth rate from 1 to 5.

Thanks!

Comment: may be sorting before computing the growth rate would do the job?

Comment: `df %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(growth = log(value) - as.numeric(lag(value)))`?

Comment: Unfortunately this returns a smaller dataset without the NA values which causes problems as I'm doing this with a dataset with quite a few columns where I want to compute growth rates, so I can't filter with just one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zoo::na.locf` will replace NAs with the last non-NA value, so this may work for you:

```
df <- df %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(
valuenoNA = zoo::na.locf(value),
growth = log(valuenoNA) - as.numeric(lag(valuenoNA)))


1      2      A         NA         2
2      5      A -0.3905621         5
3     NA      A -3.3905621         5
4      7      A -3.0540899         7
5      9      A -4.8027754         9
6      1      B         NA         1
7     NA      B -1.0000000         1
8     NA      B -1.0000000         1
9      5      B  0.6094379         5
10     6      B -3.2082405         6
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `fill` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    fill(value) %>%
    mutate(growth = log(value) - lag(value))
```